# Scraping a website that has a "Load more" button doesn't return info of newly loaded items with Beautiful Soup and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

So I'm using Selenium to press the "Load more" button and everything loads properly. Then I want to get the info of all the loaded products but I only get the info of the first 36 items that are before the first "Load more" button.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import json
import time
import requests
allinfo=[]
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
url="https://zadaa.co/de-en/products/women/clothes-dresses/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
closebutton=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div[5]/button')))
closebutton.click()
for x in range(9):
    button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "load-more-products")))
    button.click()
content=soup.find_all('a',class_='product-list-item')
for properties in content:
    brand=properties.find("p",class_='product-list-item-title').text
    info={
        'name':brand,
    }
    allinfo.append(info)
df=pd.DataFrame(allinfo)
print(df.head())
df.to_csv('zadaa.csv')
```

This is the web page I'm trying to scrape-
https://zadaa.co/de-en/products/women/clothes-dresses/

Sorry for some weird English usage.

Comment: try adding a `time.sleep(5)` after you click the load more button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate Ajax calls with `requests` module to get the data directly, without `selenium` (beware, there are 12k+ products):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://zadaa.co/de-en/products/women/clothes-dresses/"
api_url = "https://zadaa.co/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

payload = {
    "action": "get_more_products",
    "lang": "de-en",
    "security": "05ef973f4c",
    "query_id": soup.select_one("[data-query-id]")["data-query-id"],
    "offset": 0,
}


while True:
    data = requests.post(api_url, data=payload).json()
    if not data["success"]:
        break

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data["data"], "html.parser")

    for i in soup.select(".product-list-item"):
        print(i.select_one(".product-list-item-title").text)
        print(i["href"])
        print("-" * 80)

    payload["offset"] += 36
```

Prints:

```
...

CITY GIRL PARIS
https://zadaa.co/de-en/products/women/clothes-dresses/city-girl-paris/3735824/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZAFUL
https://zadaa.co/de-en/products/women/clothes-dresses/zaful/3735781/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NKD
https://zadaa.co/de-en/products/women/clothes-dresses/nkd/3735768/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GREAT RUMORS
https://zadaa.co/de-en/products/women/clothes-dresses/great-rumors/3735762/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```