# Want to scrape a whole webpage which has the loadmore button with using post method(don't wanna use selenium) through beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanna scrape some details from a main_url in which for each company it has another url for each company and get credentials of a each company from which there are some elements like company name,phone,fax,website..etc. I have write the code using beautifulsoup and requests and also got the credentials(but got only for 52 companies) .After that it giving an error of javascript cause there is loadmore button. I want to get all companies details by crossing that loadmore button too.Only wanna do with requests and beautifulsoup. Don't want to use selenium for it.I'll be glad and thankful for getting help. Here is my code till where I get good result but only having problem with load more button.

```
from time import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import requests
import json
import time

parser = 'html.parser'  # or 'lxml' (preferred) or 'html5lib', if installed
resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.arabiantalks.com/category/1/advertising-gift-articles")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, parser, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))
cnt=0

for links in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    url=(links['href'])

    # print(url)
    page=requests.get(url)
    # print(page).

    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

    # print(soup)
    results=soup.find('div',class_='rdetails')
    # print(results)
   


    if results is not None:
        # print(f"company_results: {results.text}")
        Name=results.find('h1')
        if Name is not None:
            print(f"Comapny_name: {Name.text}")
        else:
            print(f"Comapny_name: Notfound")

        address=results.find(attrs={'itemprop':'address'})
        if address is not None:
            # address.text.replace(" Address :   ", "")
            # print(type(f"Comapny_address: {address.text}"),"this type")
            print((f"Comapny_address: {address.text[12:]}"))
        else:
            print(f"Comapny_address: Notfound")
        phone=results.find(attrs={'itemprop':'telephone'})
        if phone is not None:
            print(f"Comapny_phone: {phone.text[16:]}")
        else:
            print(f"Comapny_phone: Notfound")

        fax=results.find(attrs={'itemprop':'faxNumber'})
        if fax is not None:
            print(f"Comapny_fax: {fax.text[7:]}")
        else:
            print(f"Comapny_fax: Notfound")

        email=results.find(attrs={'itemprop':'email'})
        if email is not None:
            print(f"Comapny_email: {email.text[9:]}")
        else:
            print(f"Comapny_email: Notfound")

        website=results.find(attrs={'itemprop':'url'})
        if website is not None:
            print(f"Comapny_website: {website.text}")
            
        else:
            print(f"Comapny_website: Notfound")
            
        cnt += 1

        print(cnt) 
     
        print("="*100)
```

If anyone know the ideology could you please copy these code and do required modifications and post as reply again.So I would know where to change.I tried from many articles, but still struggling.This is [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72577856/scraping-a-website-that-has-a-load-more-button-doesnt-return-info-of-newly-lo) the final link I tried.Please help me with this issue I'm pretty new in web scraping. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

This question is (almost) a duplicate of this one: [Scraping a website that has a "Load more" button doesn't return info of newly loaded items with Beautiful Soup and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72577856/scraping-a-website-that-has-a-load-more-button-doesnt-return-info-of-newly-lo)

The difference is - on this instance, the ajax response is not JSON, but HTML. You need to inspect the Network tab in browser's Dev tools, to see what network calls are being made.

The following code will access the ajax endpoint, pull all the data available, get all companies profile urls, scrape name, address, phone, fax, email, website and save everything into a csv file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

item_list = []
counter = 20

s = requests.Session()

r = s.get('https://www.arabiantalks.com/category/1/advertising-gift-articles')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('a', {'itemprop': 'item'})

for item in items:
    item_list.append(item.get('href'))

while True:
    payload = {
        'start': counter,
        'cat': 1
    }
    r = s.post('https://www.arabiantalks.com/ajax/load_content', data=payload)
    if len(r.text) < 25:
        break
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('a')
    for item in items:
        item_list.append(item.get('href'))
    counter = counter + 12
print('Total items:', len(set(item_list)))
full_comp_list = []
for x in item_list:
    r = s.get(x)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    c_details_card = soup.select_one('div.rdetails')
    try:
        c_name = c_details_card.select_one('#hcname').text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        c_name = 'Name unknown'
    try:
        c_address = c_details_card.find('h3', {'itemprop': 'address'}).text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        c_address = 'Address unknown'
    try:
        c_phone = c_details_card.find('h3', {'itemprop': 'telephone'}).text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        c_phone = 'Phone unknown'
    try:
        c_fax = c_details_card.find('h3', {'itemprop': 'faxNumber'}).text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        c_fax = 'Fax unknown'
    try:
        c_email = c_details_card.find('h3', {'itemprop': 'email'}).text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        c_email = 'Email unknown'
    try:
        c_website = c_details_card.find('a').get('href')
    except Exception as e:
        c_website = 'Website unknown'
    full_comp_list.append((c_name, c_address, c_phone, c_fax, c_email, c_website))
    print('Done', c_name)

full_df = pd.DataFrame(list(set(full_comp_list)), columns = ['Name', 'Address', 'Phone', 'Fax', 'Email', 'Website'])
full_df.to_csv('full_arabian_advertising_companies.csv')
full_df
```

It will also print out in terminal, to give you a sense of what it's doing:

```
Total items: 122
Done Ash & Sims Advertising LLC
Done Strings International Advertising LLC
Done Zaabeel Advertising LLC
Done Crystal Arc Factory LLC
Done Zone Group
Done Business Link General Trading
[....]

Name    Address Phone   Fax Email   Website
0   Ash & Sims Advertising LLC  Address : P.O.Box 50391,\nDubai - United Arab Emirates  Phone Number : +971-4-8851366 , +9714 8851366   Fax : +971-4-8852499    E-mail : sales@ashandsims.com   http://www.ashandsims.com
1   Strings International Advertising LLC   Address : P O BOX 117617\n57, Al Kawakeb Property, Al Quoz\nDubai, U.A.E    Phone Number : +971-4-3386567 , +971502503591   Fax : +971-4-3386569    E-mail : vinod@stringsinternational.org http://www.stringsinternational.org
2   Zaabeel Advertising LLC Address : Al Khabaisi,  Phone Number : +971-4-2598444   Fax : +971-4-2598448    E-mail : info@zaabeeladv.com    http://www.zaabeeladv.com
3   Crystal Arc Factory LLC Address : Dubai - P.O. Box 72282\nAl Quoz, Interchange 3, Al Manara,    Phone Number : +971-4-3479191 , +971 4 3479191, Fax : +971-4-3475535    E-mail : info@crystalarc.net    http://www.crystalarc.net
4   Zone Group  Address : Al Khalidiya opp to Rak Bank, Kamala Tower,\nOffice no.1401, PO Box 129297, Abu Dhabi, UAE    Phone Number : +97126339004 Fax : +97126339005  E-mail : info@zonegroupuae.ae   http://www.zonegroupuae.ae
[....]
```

Comment: I tried ur code by pasting it vscode and tried running but got---" raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.arabiantalks.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /category/1/advertising-gift-articles (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc3424637c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))"

Comment: I just ran it in VSCode, and it ran just fine, and it returned the result posted above. Maybe your IP got blocked or you have some connection issues, given your error, but my code is valid.

Comment: Sorry my mistake now it ran fine.But instead of printing values in list format,how can i get like this as my past code----(Comapny_name: Solutions Trading Company LLC
Comapny_address: P.O. Box # 112739 30, Al Hessn Shopping Centre, Opp.Tia Sarees, Near Choithram Supermarket, Meena Bazaar, Bur Dubai, United Arab Emirates.
Comapny_phone: +971-4-3554280 , +971 4 3554280
Comapny_fax: +971-4-3514918
Comapny_email: sales@solutionsdxb.com
Comapny_website: www.solutionsdxb.com
11)

Comment: Comapny_name: Aiconmac Models & Crystals
Comapny_address: P. O. Box 122341
B1-22 SAIF Zone
Sharjah, United Arab Emirates (UAE)
Comapny_phone: +971-6-5385363 , + 971 50 234 8 246
Comapny_fax: +971-6-5385363
Comapny_email: info@aiconmac.com
Comapny_website: www.aiconmac.com
12

Comment: You use BeautifulSoup to parse and extract the items you need, from the html response. You did it in your previous code, you should be able to do it again. If you find it difficult, then you need to read the bs4 documentation, at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Thanks for ur guidance and time.I'll try from here...

Comment: It's not hard:  `<h3>` - name, `<h4>` - address, `<h5>` - phone.

Comment: ... I updated my response, to help you get the info you need. Please review the code written, and try to understand it and learn from it.

Comment: I got ur point.But initially like(122 items), I want links like this for all 122 items because from the first page for every item it has only phone,name,address. But when u click on each item we get many other things of each company like even fax,website,etc....So finally could u please make me get only url of each item not in a list just return it in a variable and print it out like this----------------https://www.arabiantalks.com/     
https://www.arabiantalks.com/auth/register      
https://www.arabiantalks.com/auth/login     
https://www.arabiantalks.com/blog   ........etc

Comment: Total items: 122
Index(['Name', 'Address', 'Phone'], dtype='object')-----as u can see here ur getting only 3 columns.But in my previous code I'm getting total 6 columns(""""Comapny_name,
Comapny_address,
Comapny_phone,
Comapny_fax,
Comapny_email,
Comapny_website""") cause I'm going inside of each item.So in ur way only but inside each comapy url's (122) I want to fetch 6columns like above....Thank u bro for ur valuable time and if any mistake sorry for that.I'm just new to this thats'y...

Comment: Comapny_name: Genesis Promotional Products FZE
Comapny_address: Khalidiya, Opp Dana Plaza,
Comapny_phone: +971-2-6656420
Comapny_fax: +971-2-6656829
Comapny_email: auhsales@genesis-gifts.com
Comapny_website: www.genesis-gifts.com
121
====================================================================================================
Comapny_name: Arab House For Advertising Group
Comapny_address: Abu Obaidah Al Jarrah St, Muscat, Oman 
Comapny_phone: 24560588
Comapny_fax: 
Comapny_email: arabhouse@arabhouseoman.com
Comapny_website: www.arabhouseoman.com
122

Comment: Hi bro done ....Now I'm getting it all....thanks bro...really u made me to do it..

Comment: I updated my response .. my only concern is that you won't learn as much by copy/pasting: you should try to *understand* the code, then *try recreating it* yourself.

Comment: You are right bro...I'm able to understand only some terms. In my code I know all terms cause I tried by myself from here and there.But in ur code I'm not getting some terms like(counter=20) why u used that? and also didn't got [if len(r.text) < 25:] this one too . I'll try to understand bro...I f not can I ask u for help???

Comment: Hi brother ,I've one doubt as u said yesterday I understood the logic.But the only thing I (counter = 20). But when I inspect and see the payload [pay load={start: 44
cat: 2}] and payload check=[pay load content check={start: 56
cat: 2}]. I know that it's getting +12 increment each time but why did u took counter=20 at starting?

Comment: I could have initialized it from 44 (andd then increase it by 12), but I wanted to make sure there are no missing companies,  si I decided to start from 20, retrieve all, and then remove eventual duplicates at the end.

Comment: Ok. So in that case we can also initialize it from (0). Right ?But we have to make sure that it doesn't consists of any duplicate values,right?

Comment: Correct - and the following code is removing duplicates: `list(set(full_comp_list))`

Comment: If it's right this is my last doubt ,sorry for the trouble. I'm really glad that u r explaining in such a way.Ok my doubt is why we are keeping it (if len(r.text) < 25:
            break) what's the mean of (r.text and what's the scenario behind it's length. I tried printing the length and r.text but it's showing a huge text. So could u please tell me what's the meaning of it brother...?Thanks...

Comment: `r.text` is the content of the response we receive. If that response has less than 25 chars, it is very likely there is no company information in it, so there are no more companies, so we break the loop.